# Simulation of TCP sync attack in ns2

Tags: network-programming, simulation, ns2, network-security

How to simulate TCP sync attack in ns2? Please provide some guidelines that how to simulate this `DOS Attack`  in `ns2` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcp sync attack can be generated by using `AQM & DOS` simulation plateform.